# How can I find out who's trying to eject my disk?

Tags: windows-7, safely-remove-hardware

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T520 running Windows 7 Enterprise. It has an internal SSD (C:) and a second hard drive (D:) installed in place of the DVD drive. At various times throughout the day, a window pops up which says "This device is currently in use. Close any programs or windows that might be using the device, and then try again". The device specified is always the second hard drive. But I'm not trying to eject the disk, and I don't want it ejected in any case.

How can I find out what process is trying to eject it?

Comment: Might be a problem with the hard drive's caddy. Can you possibly try another one to confirm?

Comment: Have you checked if there is some messages logged in the Windows Event Log at the time when the popup appears?